# Querying array of text in postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, performance

I have an array type I want to store in Postgres. One of the major use cases I have is to see if any of the records has an array which has a string in it.

eg.

```
| A | ["NY", "Paris", "Milan"] |
| B | ["Paris", "NY"]          |
| C | []                       |
| D | ["Milan"]                |
```

Does there exist a row with `Paris` in the array? Which rows have `Milan` in the array? and so on.

I have 2 options on how to store the column. I can either make it a type `text[]` or convert it into a json as `{"cities": ["NY", "Paris", "Milan"]}` and then store as a `JSONB` field

However, I am not sure what would allow the fastest querying for the use case I have. Is there any one obviously better way of doing this? Am I tying myself down in any way by choosing one over the other? If I choose one over the other then how can I query the DB?

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to be storing simple lists of values, I would recommend to use datataype `Array` over `JSON`, which better fits more complex cases (nested datastructures, associative arrays, ...).

To check for the value of an element at any position in the array, you can use array function `ANY()`.

Here is a query that will return all records where the array stored in column `cities` contains `'Paris'` :

```
SELECT t.* FROM mytable t WHERE 'Paris' = ANY(t.cities);
```

Yields :

```
id  cities
---------------------------
A   ["NY","Paris","Milan"]
B   ["Paris","NY"]
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7z2XH1ARw6hazCYguCdWfh/0)**

For more information :

- [Postgres Arrays Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html)
- [Postgres Arrays Tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-array/)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed it is better to query JSONB, if it is a simple key-value store. 
As in for instance you want to store arbitrary info on a row that your not sure what the columns(keys) would be.
info = {"a":"apple", "b":"ball"}

For use cases like yours, it would be better if you could design the db with simple tables so you could use JOINS and Indexes to your advantage.

You could restructure the tables like :

### Location

```
id | name
----------
1  | Paris
2  | NY
3  | Milan
```

### Other Table (with foreign key on location table)

```
user | location_id
--------------------
A    | 1
A    | 3
B    | 2
```

Using these set of tables it would be easy to query all users with location *paris* using JOINS.